# ngModel not working with pipe number

Tags: angular

I have this in my html:

```
<input class="ui-g-4 right" [ngModel]="product.unitprice | number:'1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="updateUnitPrice(i,$event);sumTotal(i)">
```

Problem is when i enter something like this 3412in input i get 3412,00 but in console i get an error

```
InvalidPipeArgument: '3412,00' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'
```

My methods:

```
sumTotal(i,e){
    this.products[i].itemamount = (this.products[i].quantity * parseFloat(this.products[i].unitprice.toLocaleString())) - parseInt(this.products[i].discountamount ? this.products[i].discountamount.toLocaleString() : '0');
}
updateUnitPrice(i,e){
    this.products[i].unitprice = +e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be **`[ngModel]`**

```
<input class="ui-g-4 right" [(ngModel)]="product.unitprice | number:'1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="updateUnitPrice(i,$event);sumTotal(i)">
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blyiux?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: check the demo abov

Comment: its okey with display but i can change value of that input then i get an error

Comment: then you should check the function,  called on ngModelchange updateUnitPrice post the method

Comment: i only do this : this.products[i].unitprice = e; and thats it

Comment: thats where the issue is post both the methods sumtotal as well

Comment: i posted my both methods

Answer (score 0):

Your model `product.unitprice` needs to have a valid number 3412,00 you need to format your input so it's a valid decimal number for instance 3412.00

Another option is to convert your string to a number like so `Number(product.unitprice)`

It could also be your adding `e` this should be `e.target.value` to get the actual value.